# Why would socket_connect() return error #2: "No such file or directory"?

Tags: php, sockets

I wrote a simple socket server in C++ that I'm going to use to communicate between a few other daemons.  The server itself is fine; it's listening for TCP connections on port 3000.  A `netstat` shows the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)
tcp4       0      0  *.30000                *.*                    LISTEN
```

However, in PHP, if I use the following few simple lines of code:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_connect($sock, '127.0.0.1', 30000);
```

I get the following:

```
Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [2]:
No such file or directory in /foo/bar/baz.php on line 8
```

Is this the right protocol (`0`) to use for IPC sockets?  It's probably something dumb that I've overlooked - any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `AF_UNIX` with `AF_INET` (or `PF_INET` - see [Protocol and address families](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#Protocol_and_address_families)) to create a TCP/IP socket (I'm assuming that's what you want since you are trying to connect to an IP address). As written now the `socket_create` call creates a [Unix socket](http://www.manpagez.com/man/4/unix/) - which is mapped to an object on a file system, hence the error message.

Comment: So... maybe this is a dumb question - but let's say that I don't want to use INET sockets; these connections will always be local.  Is that advantageous to using a TCP/IP socket?  I'm assuming there has to be at least a little more overhead doing the latter, but I don't see how a non-TCP/IP socket could be used across a distributed system, for example.

Comment: inet sockets over loopback (`127.0.0.1` is the address of the local "virtual" network interface) are pretty efficient - they are just memory copies into and out of the kernel. Unix sockets have some additional features like file descriptor and credentials passing, but these are not available outside of that one machine.